# Read Soap Headers in ASMX

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsdl, asmx

I have two issues
First, for a couple of my methods I want to pass account information in the soap:Header and then validate that information.   It is not reading the information passed in the soap:Header.  I have spent the last 3 days on Google looking at numerous examples and they all show something similar to what I have in place.  Yet, every time I try it I am not getting a value for either of the nodes

Here is the code showing one of the methods

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using DataAccess;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using SchemaValidation;


namespace CRI_Assessments
{

    [WebService(Namespace = "http://www.criw.net/AssessmentServices")]
    [WebServiceBinding(Name = "CustomWSDL", Location = "Assessments.wsdl")]
    public class AuthHeader : SoapHeader
    {
        public string Master;
        public string Secondary;
    }

    [WebService(Namespace = "http://www.criw.net/AssessmentServices")]
    [WebServiceBinding(Name = "CustomWSDL", Location = "Assessments.wsdl")]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]

    public class AssessmentServices : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        public AuthHeader Authentication = new AuthHeader();

        private bool Authenticate(AuthHeader credentials)
        {
            string master = Authentication.Master;
            string secondary = Authentication.Secondary;

            DataManager DBMgr = null;
            DBMgr = DBCon.GetDataManager();
            DBMgr.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionStringVHRC"].ToString();
            DBMgr.Open();

            DBMgr.CreateParameters(2);
            DBMgr.AddParameters(0, "@Master", master);
            DBMgr.AddParameters(1, "@Secondary", secondary);
            object isValid = DBMgr.ExecuteScalar(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "ValidateMasterAndSecondary");
            bool Valid = Convert.ToBoolean(isValid == DBNull.Value ? "0" : isValid);
            return Valid;
        }


        [WebMethod(Description = "This method is used to get the questions and answers for a section of the assessment.  If the section is meant to be timed it will be indicated along with the number of seconds the user should be given before their answers are submitted. For the untimed sections where all questions must be answered, the RequireAllQuestionsAnswered node will indicate if all questions must be answered before the information is submitted.  Additionally, for assessments with a personality section there is a node indicating how many middle answers are allowed.  You should put code in place to ensure the evaluee does not go over that limit. For assessments that use numerical perception you will be given the 3 values used to build the page.  The question number, left column and right column ", BufferResponse = true)]
        [SoapHeader("Authentication")]
        //[Validation]
        public XmlDocument GetSection(int AssessmentID, int FinishedSection, string Language)
        {

            DataManager DBMgr = null;
            DataTable dtValidate = new DataTable();
            string results = string.Empty;
            XmlDocument myXml = new XmlDocument();
            int nextSection;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            string myData = string.Empty;
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sb);

            writer.WriteStartDocument();

            try
            {
                if (Authenticate(Authentication))
                {

                int languageID = 0;
                    DBMgr = null;

                    DBMgr = DBCon.GetDataManager();
                    DBMgr.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionStringCRISupport"].ToString();
                    DBMgr.Open();
                    //Get languageID of the Assessment
                    DBMgr.CreateParameters(1);
                    DBMgr.AddParameters(0, "@LanguageCode", Language);
                    object langid = DBMgr.ExecuteScalar(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "GetlanguageID");
                    languageID = Convert.ToInt32(langid == DBNull.Value ? "0" : langid);
                    if (languageID == 0)
                    {
                        writer.WriteStartElement("ErrorMessage");
                        writer.WriteValue("Invalid language.");
                        writer.WriteEndElement();
                        writer.WriteEndDocument();

                        writer.Flush();
                    }

                    DBMgr = null;

                    DBMgr = DBCon.GetDataManager();
                    DBMgr.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionStringCRISupport"].ToString();
                    DBMgr.Open();

                    DBMgr.CreateParameters(2);
                    DBMgr.AddParameters(0, "@AssessmentID", AssessmentID);
                    DBMgr.AddParameters(1, "@Sequence", FinishedSection);
                    object theSection = DBMgr.ExecuteScalar(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "CRI_GetNextSectionInSequence");
                    nextSection = Convert.ToInt32(theSection == DBNull.Value ? "0" : theSection);

                    DataTable dtQuestions = new DataTable();
                    DataTable dtInfo = new DataTable();
                    bool customQuestions = false;
                    bool TimedSection = false;
                    bool answerAll = false;
                    string AssessmentName = string.Empty;
                    int AllotedSeconds = 0;

                    DBMgr = null;
                    DBMgr = DBCon.GetDataManager();
                    DBMgr.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionStringCRISupport"].ToString();
                    DBMgr.Open();

                    DBMgr.CreateParameters(1);
                    DBMgr.AddParameters(0, "@AssessmentID", AssessmentID);
                    dtInfo = DBMgr.ExecuteDataTable(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "CRI_GetAssessmentData");
                    if (dtInfo.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        customQuestions = Convert.ToBoolean(dtInfo.Rows[0]["UsesCustom"]);
                        AssessmentName = Convert.ToString(dtInfo.Rows[0]["ShortName"]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        writer.WriteStartElement("ErrorMessage");
                        writer.WriteValue("Invalid assessmentID - No information found for assessmentID " + Convert.ToString(AssessmentID));
                        writer.WriteEndElement();
                        writer.WriteEndDocument();

                        writer.Flush();

                    }
                    writer.WriteStartElement("Assessment");

                    writer.WriteStartElement("AssessmentID");
                    writer.WriteValue(AssessmentID);
                    writer.WriteEndElement();

                    writer.WriteStartElement("AssessmentName");
                    writer.WriteValue(AssessmentName);
                    writer.WriteEndElement();

                    writer.WriteStartElement("SectionID");
                    writer.WriteValue(nextSection);
                    writer.WriteEndElement();

                    switch (nextSection)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            TimedSection = false;
                            answerAll = true;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            TimedSection = true;
                            answerAll = false;
                            AllotedSeconds = 900;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            TimedSection = true;
                            answerAll = false;
                            AllotedSeconds = 300;
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            TimedSection = true;
                            answerAll = false;
                            AllotedSeconds = 240;
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            TimedSection = true;
                            answerAll = false;
                            AllotedSeconds = 180;
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            TimedSection = false;
                            answerAll = false;
                            break;
                        case 7:
                            TimedSection = true;
                            answerAll = false;
                            AllotedSeconds = 660;
                            break;
                        case 8:
                            TimedSection = false;
                            answerAll = true;
                            break;
                        default:
                            TimedSection = false;
                            break;
                    }

                    if (TimedSection)
                    {
                        writer.WriteStartElement("SectionTiming");
                        writer.WriteStartElement("TimedSection");
                        writer.WriteValue("True");
                        writer.WriteEndElement();
                        writer.WriteStartElement("AllotedSeconds");
                        writer.WriteValue(AllotedSeconds);
                        writer.WriteEndElement();
                        writer.WriteEndElement();

                    }

                    writer.WriteStartElement("RequireAllQuestionsAnswered");
                    writer.WriteValue(answerAll);
                    writer.WriteEndElement();

                    if (FinishedSection == 0)
                    {
                        int middlesAllowed = 0;
                        DataTable dtMids = new DataTable();
                        DBMgr = null;
                        DBMgr = DBCon.GetDataManager();
                        DBMgr.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionStringCRISupport"].ToString();
                        DBMgr.Open();

                        DBMgr.CreateParameters(1);
                        DBMgr.AddParameters(0, "@AssessmentID", AssessmentID);
                        dtMids = DBMgr.ExecuteDataTable(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "CRI_GetAllowedMiddles");
                        if (dtMids.Rows.Count > 0)
                        {
                            middlesAllowed = Convert.ToInt32(dtMids.Rows[0]["PersonalityMiddles"]);
                        }
                        writer.WriteStartElement("AllowedMiddleAnswers");
                        writer.WriteValue(middlesAllowed);
                        writer.WriteEndElement();
                    }
                    writer.WriteStartElement("QuestionList");
                    DBMgr = null;
                    DBMgr = DBCon.GetDataManager();
                    DBMgr.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionStringCRISupport"].ToString();
                    DBMgr.Open();

                    DBMgr.CreateParameters(4);
                    DBMgr.AddParameters(0, "@SectionID", nextSection);
                    DBMgr.AddParameters(1, "@LanguageID", languageID);
                    DBMgr.AddParameters(2, "@AssessmentID", AssessmentID);
                    DBMgr.AddParameters(3, "@Custom", customQuestions);
                    dtQuestions = DBMgr.ExecuteDataTable(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "GetAssessmentQuestionsAndAnswers");
                    foreach (DataRow row in dtQuestions.Rows)
                    {
                        if (nextSection != 5)
                        {
                            string Sequence = Convert.ToString(row["Sequence"]);
                            string Question = Convert.ToString(row["QuestionText"]);
                            string Answer1 = Convert.ToString(row["Answer1"]);
                            string Answer2 = Convert.ToString(row["Answer2"]);
                            string Answer3 = Convert.ToString(row["Answer3"]);
                            string Answer4 = Convert.ToString(row["Answer4"]);
                            string Answer5 = Convert.ToString(row["Answer5"]);
                            writer.WriteStartElement("Question");
                            writer.WriteStartElement("QuestionNumber");
                            writer.WriteValue(Sequence);
                            writer.WriteEndElement();
                            writer.WriteStartElement("QuestionText");
                            writer.WriteValue(Question);
                            writer.WriteEndElement();
                            writer.WriteStartElement("Answer");
                            writer.WriteStartElement("Sequence");
                            writer.WriteValue("1");
                            writer.WriteEndElement();
                            writer.WriteStartElement("AnswerText");
                            writer.WriteValue(Answer1);
                            writer.WriteEndElement();
                            writer.WriteEndElement();
                            writer.WriteStartElement("Answer");
                            writer.WriteStartElement("Sequence");
                            writer.WriteValue("2");
                            writer.WriteEndElement();
                            writer.WriteStartElement("AnswerText");
                            writer.WriteValue(Answer2);
                            writer.WriteEndElement();
                            writer.WriteEndElement();
                            writer.WriteStartElement("Answer");
                            writer.WriteStartElement("Sequence");
                            writer.WriteValue("3");
                            writer.WriteEndElement();
                            writer.WriteStartElement("AnswerText");
                            writer.WriteValue(Answer3);
                            writer.WriteEndElement();
                            writer.WriteEndElement();
                            if (Answer4 != "")
                            {
                                writer.WriteStartElement("Answer");
                                writer.WriteStartElement("Sequence");
                                writer.WriteValue("4");
                                writer.WriteEndElement();
                                writer.WriteStartElement("AnswerText");
                                writer.WriteValue(Answer4);
                                writer.WriteEndElement();
                                writer.WriteEndElement();
                            }
                            if (Answer5 != "")
                            {
                                writer.WriteStartElement("Answer");
                                writer.WriteStartElement("Sequence");
                                writer.WriteValue("5");
                                writer.WriteEndElement();
                                writer.WriteStartElement("AnswerText");
                                writer.WriteValue(Answer5);
                                writer.WriteEndElement();
                                writer.WriteEndElement();
                            }
                            writer.WriteEndElement();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            string Sequence = Convert.ToString(row["QuestionID"]);
                            string leftNumber = Convert.ToString(row["LeftNumber"]);
                            string rightNumber = Convert.ToString(row["RightNumber"]);
                            writer.WriteStartElement("Question");
                            writer.WriteStartElement("QuestionNumber");
                            writer.WriteValue(Sequence);
                            writer.WriteEndElement();
                            writer.WriteStartElement("LeftColumn");
                            writer.WriteValue(leftNumber);
                            writer.WriteEndElement();
                            writer.WriteStartElement("RightColumn");
                            writer.WriteValue(rightNumber);
                            writer.WriteEndElement();
                            writer.WriteEndElement();
                        }
                    }
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                    writer.WriteEndDocument();

                    writer.Flush();

                }
                else
                {
                    writer.WriteStartElement("ErrorMessage");
                    writer.WriteValue("Soap authentication has incorrect value(s) passed in the AuthHeader.");
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                    writer.WriteEndDocument();

                    writer.Flush();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                writer.WriteStartElement("ErrorMessage");
                writer.WriteValue(ex.Message);
                writer.WriteEndElement();
                writer.WriteEndDocument();

                writer.Flush();
            }

            myXml.LoadXml(sb.ToString());
            return myXml;
        }



    }
}
```

My 2nd problem is I need to use a custom wsdl so that I can validate the incoming soap message.  This works until I add the soap:Header and then I get the following error message.

```
soap:ClientSystem.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Incoming message failed validation: Warning: Could not find schema information for the element 'http:www.criw.net/AssessmentServices:AuthHeader'. at SchemaValidation.ValidationExtension.xrs_ValidationEventHandler(Object sender, ValidationEventArgs e) in k:\SchemaValidation\Extensions\ValidationExtension.cs:line 437 at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidator.SendValidationEvent(XmlSchemaValidationException e, XmlSeverityType severity) at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidator.SendValidationEvent(String code, String msg, XmlSeverityType severity) at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidator.ThrowDeclNotFoundWarningOrError(Boolean declFound) at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidator.ValidateElement(String localName, String namespaceUri, XmlSchemaInfo schemaInfo, String xsiType, String xsiNil, String xsiSchemaLocation, String xsiNoNamespaceSchemaLocation) at System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.ProcessElementEvent() at System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.ProcessReaderEvent() at System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.Read() at SchemaValidation.ValidationExtension.ProcessMessage(SoapMessage message) in k:\SchemaValidation\Extensions\ValidationExtension.cs:line 350 at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapMessage.RunExtensions(SoapExtension[] extensions, Boolean throwOnException) at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.ReadParameters() at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()http://www.criw.net/Assessment_WebService/AssessmentServices.asmx
```

here is a sample of the soap message I sent

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Header>
    <AuthHeader xmlns="http:www.criw.net/AssessmentServices">
        <Master>TEST</Master>
        <Secondary>TEST</Secondary>
    </AuthHeader>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
    <GetSection xmlns="http://www.criw.net/AssessmentServices">
        <AssessmentID>1</AssessmentID>
        <FinishedSection>0</FinishedSection>
        <Language>en</Language>
    </GetSection>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The web service can be found here
http://www.criw.net/Assessment_WebService/AssessmentServices.asmx

the WSDL I am validating against is here
http://www.criw.net/Assessment_WebService/Assessments.wsdl

I would appreciate any and all help

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: Thanks,  but that does not answer the question.  Who really cares if it is legacy or not?    I know that I don't.  (our company has millions of lines of code in classic asp still)     I looked at WCF but  every tutorial I found talks about the client.  I don't care about the client.  The companies that use our service may write their code in any language they want.   All I want to do is secure our information so that any tom dick or harry cannot access the info if they do not have an account.